# Approximation in fractional Sobolev space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, sobolev-spaces, fractional-calculus

Assume $\Omega\subset \Bbb R^d$ is Lipschitz open set. Let $p\geq 1$ and $0<s\leq 1/p$.

How to prove that $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ is dense in $W^{s,p}(\Omega)$?

Recall that,

$$|u|^p_{W^{s,p}(\Omega)}= \iint\limits_{\Omega\Omega}\frac{|u(x)-u(y)|^p}{|x-y|^{d+sp}}dx dy$$
and

$$W^{s,p}(\Omega)= \{u\in L^p(\Omega): |u|^p_{W^{s,p}(\Omega)}<\infty\}$$

equipped with the Banach norm

$$\|u\|^p_{W^{s,p}(\Omega)}= \|u\|^p_{L^{p}(\Omega)}+|u|^p_{W^{s,p}(\Omega)}$$

The main difficulty in solving this is to construct a suitable family of cut-off with compact support in $\Omega$.

Comment: just a little comment with a very recent reference https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.08000 where similar questions are addressed on $\mathbb{R}^d$ and where related questions are asked for domain $\Omega$ of $\mathbb{R}^d$. See also Reference 7 of this manuscript.

Comment: @user69642 I have looked up the references. But They do not address my concern. The first one deals with homogeneous spaces in $\Bbb R^n$ and the second article deals Dirichlet's spaces. I expected to find something the reference [7].

Comment: I know. That's why it is a comment..